# How to change physics body and sprite image of existing sprite after contact

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I have created two sprites with physics bodies and handled their contact. How can I change the physics body and sprite image for one of sprites when the contact occurs? Please see relevant code below:

```
// circle Sprite
circleSprite.name = circleSpriteCategoryName
circleSprite.position = CGPointMake(2*self.frame.size.width/3, 2*self.frame.size.height/3)
circleSprite.zPosition = 10
self.addChild(circleSprite)
circleSprite.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius:  circleSprite.frame.size.width/2)
circleSprite.physicsBody?.friction = 0
circleSprite.physicsBody?.restitution = 1
circleSprite.physicsBody?.linearDamping = 0
circleSprite.physicsBody?.angularDamping = 0
circleSprite.physicsBody?.allowsRotation = false
circleSprite.physicsBody?.applyImpulse(CGVectorMake(4, -4))

// square sprite
let squareSprite = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "square.png")
squareSprite.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetWidth(frame)*0.4, CGRectGetHeight(frame)*0.8)
squareSprite.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: squareSprite.frame.size)
squareSprite.physicsBody?.friction = 0.0
squareSprite.name = squareSpriteCategoryName
squareSprite.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = squareSpriteCategory
squareSprite.zPosition = 10
addChild(squareSprite)

// contact in didBeginContact
if firstBody.categoryBitMask == circleSpriteCategory && secondBody.categoryBitMask == squareSpriteCategory  {
        println("contact works")
    }
```

**EDIT 1**

I would like to change update the physics body and image of `circleSprite` to have the following properties:

```
circleSprite = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "recto.png")
circleSprite.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: circleSprite.frame.size)
circleSprite.physicsBody?.friction = 0.0
circleSprite.name = newSpriteCategoryName
circleSprite.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = newSpriteCategory
```

**EDIT 2**

I managed to get change the sprite image thanks to help from Max_Power89. But the image has been reduced to the dimensions of the physics body. Please see the relevant code below:

```
        if firstBody.categoryBitMask == circleSpriteCategory && secondBody.categoryBitMask == squareSpriteCategory    {

        if let newSprite = firstBody.node    {
            let newImage = SKTexture(imageNamed: "newSprite.png")
            let action = SKAction.setTexture(newImage)
            newSprite.runAction(action)
          }
      }
```

Comment: If you want to resize the SKSpriteNode after changing its texture, you can always get the size of the new texture with the newImage.size() method.  So you could set newSprite.size = newImage.size(). Hope that helps!

Comment: @Stephen I tried `newImage.frame.size = newImage.size` but I keep getting a `cannot assign to the result of this expression` error. Still got the error when I changed the `newSprite` from `let` to `var`. I'm not sure what's causing this error

Comment: You want to change the size of the sprite, so try something like: "newSprite.size = newImage.size()". Your code is trying to assign to the newImage.frame.

Comment: @Stephen Sorry, I made a mistake, I tried `newSprite.frame.size`.  `newSprite = firstBody.node` so I can't access the `size` property directly this gives the `annot assign to the result of this expression error`

Comment: Ah! I believe you just need to cast newSprite as an SKSpriteNode to access the size property. Something like this: "(newSprite as? SKSpriteNode)?.size = newImage.size()"

Comment: didn't think about that. Thanks, it's working

Answer (score 0):

You can implement `SKPhysicsContactDelegate`

then in your `didBeginContact` delegate you can do something like this

```
func didBeginContact(contact: SKPhysicsContact) {
        // Return whatever it's the other body
        let other = contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask == PhisicsCategory.Player ? contact.bodyB : contact.bodyA
        if other.categoryBitMask == PhisicsCategory.Playe1 {
            //Change sprite
            let deadTexture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "Your image name")
            let action = SKAction.setTexture(deadTexture)
            player1.runAction(action)
        }
    }
```

Comment: I don't really understand your answer.  I just updated the question

Comment: The delegate [SKPhysicsContactDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKPhysicsContactDelegate_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/SKPhysicsContactDelegate) it's used to detect a collision between 2 objects. When that collision it's detected the delegate it's trigger and then inside that method you can change the sprite image and all the properties that you want to change!

Comment: I kinda get your explanation but the code example above doesn't follow. I believe `Player` is an `SKNodeSprite` but it looks as if you're setting it as a physics body. I guess that's what got me confused. I'll try it.

Comment: the line 'contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask == PhisicsCategory.Player ? contact.bodyB : contact.bodyA' it's just to know how is the other player the I collide with. It's just an example, you can use other system if you prefer. ' PhisicsCategory.Player' it's a category that I've create to better identifier the players. but feel free to use some other way if you prefer

Comment: thanks, I have made some progress. Please check the new edit (EDIT 2) I just updated, but I can't get the original sprite image size.

Comment: @NSologistic does the new image has the same resolution of the first image?